# Page style stuttering/dancing on load

Tags: javascript, html, css, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a .NET MVC project in which records are displayed on a table.

When I first load my page, the table I have set up does this little 'dance'. I don't know how else to describe it. See below:

[image]

I thought this might have something to do with my CSS overriding Bootstrap. But when I took out the Bootstrap class references from my view, it still happens.

This started happening after I added this CSS to my file:

```
<style>
    table {
        /*table-layout:fixed;*/
    }
    td {
        max-width: 120px;
    }
    .text-box {
        max-width: 100px;
    }

</style>
```

At this point, I'm just not sure how to troubleshoot this, and it's difficult to find anything on this topic. What could possibly cause this?

Comment: it might be that you load certain scripts asynchronously or at the end of the page, and the table shows wider until they load.

Comment: can you just set your `<table>` to `width: 100%;` ?

Comment: Brino!
Thanks, I think this was it. I moved my style section above everything else and it stopped.